# What math technique is used to get $k\left(\sqrt{r_o^2+x^2}-r_o\right) \approx kr_o \left(1+\frac12 \frac{x^2}{r_o^2}-1\right)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, electromagnetism

How is this equation in left-hand side, approximately equal to the right hand side? What math technique is used?
$$k\left(\sqrt{r_o^2+x^2}-r_o\right) \approx kr_o \left(1+\frac12 \frac{x^2}{r_o^2}-1\right)$$

If you need more context, here it is: this is from electrical engineering; electromagnetism; antenna arrays;

Question:
[image]

Answer:
[image]

In part b, I need to find a maximum distance limit where phase error of antenna beam would be valid. I understand everything until the eqn. they got from approximating.

I have all the information, there is no more info to add.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
k\left(\sqrt{r_o^2+x^2}-r_o\right)
&=
k\left(\sqrt{r_o^2\left(1+\frac{x^2}{r_o^2}\right)}-r_o\right) \\
&= k\left(r_o \sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{r_o^2}}-r_o\right) \\
&= kr_o \left(\sqrt{1+ \frac{x^2}{r_o^2}}-1\right) \\
&\approx kr_o \left(1+\frac12 \frac{x^2}{r_o^2}-1\right).
\end{align}

The approximation from the last step comes from this Taylor series:
$$\sqrt{1+x} = 1 +\frac12 x -\frac18 x^2 +\frac1{16} x^3 -\frac5{128} x^4 +\frac7{256} x^5 +\ldots$$
For small $x$, values like $x^2$, $x^3$, et cetera, can be neglected.

Answer (score 3):

This is the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$ which is equal to
$$
\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac12x-\frac18x^2+...
$$
For small values of $x$ the terms $x^2$ etc. can be discarded.